# How to obtain surfaces tag in Gmsh Python api?

Tags: python, api, boundary, fenics, gmsh

i am trying to generate geometries and meshes with the Python api of Gmsh, planning to use it in FEniCS.

I started creating my geometry following the steps reported here: https://jsdokken.com/src/tutorial_gmsh.html

The author first create the volume and then retrieve the surfaces with the command:

```
surfaces = gmsh.model.occ.getEntities(dim=2)
```

Finally, he is able to relate the surface to the tag simply by finding the center of mass (com). He uses the command gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(dim,tag) and compares it with the know com position of his surfaces, like this:

```
inlet_marker, outlet_marker, wall_marker, obstacle_marker = 1, 3, 5, 7
walls = []
obstacles = []
for surface in surfaces:
    com = gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(surface[0], surface[1])
    if np.allclose(com, [0, B/2, H/2]):
        gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(surface[0], [surface[1]], inlet_marker)
        inlet = surface[1]
        gmsh.model.setPhysicalName(surface[0], inlet_marker, "Fluid inlet")
    elif np.allclose(com, [L, B/2, H/2]):
        gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(surface[0], [surface[1]], outlet_marker)
        gmsh.model.setPhysicalName(surface[0], outlet_marker, "Fluid outlet")
    elif np.isclose(com[2], 0) or np.isclose(com[1], B) or np.isclose(com[2], H) or np.isclose(com[1],0):
        walls.append(surface[1])
    else:
        obstacles.append(surface[1])
```

Now, my problem is that this cannot work if two or more surfaces share the same com, such as two concentric cylinders.

How can i discriminate between them in such situation?
For example in case of an hollow cylinder, i would like to have a tag for each surface in order to apply different boundary conditions in FEniCS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `gmsh.model.getAdjacencies(dim,tag)` where `dim` and `tag` are the dimension and tag of your entity of interest. This functions returns two lists `up, down`. The first one gives you the tags of all entities adjacent (=neighbouring) to the entity of interest with dimension `dim + 1`. The second list gives you the tags of all entities adjacent to the entity of interest with dimension `dim - 1`.

In 3D (i.e. `dim = 3`) the `up` list will be empty because there are no 4D structures in gmsh. The `down` list will contain all surface tags the boundary of the volume is made of.

Below is an example code. Part 1 is straight forward and in Part 2 I added a functions that sorts the surface tags by their x-coordinate.

```
import gmsh

gmsh.initialize()

## PART 1:
tag_cylinder_1 = gmsh.model.occ.addCylinder(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.1)
tag_cylinder_2 = gmsh.model.occ.addCylinder(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.2)
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()

up_cyl_1, down_cyl_1 = gmsh.model.getAdjacencies(3,tag_cylinder_1)
up_cyl_2, down_cyl_2 = gmsh.model.getAdjacencies(3,tag_cylinder_2)

com_1 = gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(2, down_cyl_1[0])
com_2 = gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(2, down_cyl_1[1])
com_3 = gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(2, down_cyl_1[2])


## PART 2:

def calcBoxVolume(box):
    dx = box[3] - box[0]    
    dy = box[4] - box[1] 
    dz = box[5] - box[2] 
    
    return dx*dy*dz

def getOrderedTags(cylTag):
    up, down = gmsh.model.getAdjacencies(3,cylTag)
    surf_COM = []
    for surface in down:
        com = [surface] + list(gmsh.model.occ.getCenterOfMass(2, surface))
        surf_COM.append(com)
        
    orderedSurfaces = sorted(surf_COM,key = lambda x: x[1])
    orderedSurfaceTags = [item[0] for item in orderedSurfaces]
    return orderedSurfaceTags

def setPhysicalTags(name,cylTag):
    orderedSurfaces = getOrderedTags(cylTag)
    
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [orderedSurfaces[0]],name="inlet_"+name)
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [orderedSurfaces[1]],name="tube_"+name)
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [orderedSurfaces[3]],name="outlet_"+name)
    
def setPhysicalTagsCylDiff(name,cylTag):
    orderedSurfaces = getOrderedTags(cylTag)
    
    tag_A = orderedSurfaces[1]
    tag_B = orderedSurfaces[2]
    
    box_tube_A = gmsh.model.getBoundingBox(2,tag_A)
    box_tube_B = gmsh.model.getBoundingBox(2,tag_B)
    
    volBoxA = calcBoxVolume(box_tube_A)
    volBoxB = calcBoxVolume(box_tube_B)
    
    if volBoxA > volBoxB:
        innerTag = tag_B
        outerTag = tag_A
    else:
        innerTag = tag_A
        outerTag = tag_B
    
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [orderedSurfaces[0]],name="inlet_"+name)
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [innerTag],name="tube_inner_"+name)
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [outerTag],name="tube_outer_"+name)
    gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [orderedSurfaces[3]],name="outlet_"+name)
    
# setPhysicalTags("Cylinder_1",tag_cylinder_1)
# setPhysicalTags("Cylinder_2",tag_cylinder_2)

outDimTags, outDimTagsMap = gmsh.model.occ.cut([(3,tag_cylinder_2)],[(3,tag_cylinder_1)])
cylDiffTag = outDimTags[0][1]
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()
setPhysicalTagsCylDiff("CylDiff",cylDiffTag)

gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)
gmsh.fltk.run()
gmsh.finalize()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have a couple of questions: First of all, if i understand correctly you are sorting the surfaces for each cylinder separately, according to the x coordinete of the com. Am i right? It seems to work but, what if i want to use the command "gmsh.model.occ.cut" between the two cylinders (since i don't want to mesh the inside)? in this case i end up with a single volume and two of its surfaces share the same com. Am i missing something from your code?

Comment: I changed the code example, have a look. If you cut one cylinder out of another, you will indeed have two "tube"-like surfaces, the inner one and the outer one, which have the same center of mass. However the bounding box of both surfaces is different. This is what I am using in the new code. The inner tube will have smaller volume of the bounding box than the outer tube.

Comment: Thank you again, i think this will solve my problem. Probably the combination of the volumetric method with the sorted() command is suffeciently general for my purposes.